# Retrieve exception messages in php to keep an error history

Tags: php, exception

I have a class that analyzes files and process them. in the processing, there are many possile exceptions to throw. I want a way to manage the exception messages, by keeping them in a variable, with the name of the file, so that I can show them in a history page. What would be the best practice to do that?

I define the exception class like this:

```
   class ProcessorException extends \Exception implements ExceptionInterface
    {

    }
```

Inside the class I have:

> `::: EDIT :::`

```
if ( filesize($filename) == 0) {
                 throw new ProcessorException('File is empty');
                }
elseif ((is_dir($filename)) {
                 throw new ProcessorException('File is a directory');
}
else {
throw new ProcessorException('File error unkonwn');
}
```

How to get the message inside the exception class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when you say historic is for all requests:

I would create a log file / php table and i would write a line/INSERT for each exception, storing the info that you want (Source code, line, exception type, date, etc).

If it is in just a unique PHP file execution i would create an empty array adding with each exception for example an object, where you store all the exceptions (just create an object and add attributes inside the exception handler). And then display it at the end of the run.

Comment: How to store the info? will I need to instanciate the exception like this every time : `ProcessorException ex = new ProcessorException('message');
$array_error[] = $ex->getMessage();  `

Comment: In runtime when using the object just try {
    //use the object
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //  $e->getMessage() 
   //Store exception
}

Comment: Another option is inside the class, then you would need to do this for each "throw new ProcessorException"

Comment: Could you check the edit in the question please ? infact I have conditions, if they are true then the exception is thrown

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php , you will probably need to modify the constructor to get the message